# Fill a list with pointers - c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill a list with pointers in one class and use it in another class but i always take the same result. I know that i must create a new object every time but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance. Here is the code:

```
list<Class1*> FillList() {  //Class1 is a superclass

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  //mvar is a Class1 object pointer
    mvar = new Class1;
    mvar = next();  //returns &Class2 (subclass) object witch has "ID" (int) and
                    //"Terms" (string) as parameters

    if (mvar->ID() != -1) { 
      mlist.push_back(mvar);
      mvar = NULL; 
    }    
}
return mlist;
mlist.clear(); 
}


//Use of FillList in the other class

 list<Class1*> mlist2 = object->FillList();  //returns mlist

 while (mlist2.front()->id() != -1) {

        index(mlist2.front());  //do something with it - Expects Class1 pointer
        ...
        mlist2 = object->FillList();
}
```

*I tried to use:

```
mlist.push_back(new Class1(mvar->ID());
```

instead of:

```
mlist.push_back(mvar);.
```

and it works but when the program gets to index() the function expects a Class1 object pointer instead of an int (which is the type of the ID() )

Comment: `return mlist; mlist.clear();` - are you aware that `mlist.clear();` will never get executed?

Comment: There are some strange things going on here. You set `mvar` to a newly allocated object, but then immediately replace it again with the result of `next()` - this is a memory leak. Changing `mlist2` continuously without freeing the contained pointers is also suspicious.

Comment: Your question has not really become clear to me. Could you create some compilable example and try to state in other words what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to get your head around the idea of a virtual clone function to copy derived types via a base class pointer.  Afterwards you'd be ready to have another crack at this.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
mvar = new Class1;
mvar = next();
```

overwrites the only pointer you had to the brand-new `Class1` object, leaking it.  You have to create only the object you want to keep.  You can't create objects in steps, and there is no garbage collection to fix mistakes like this.

Comment: You are right. If I keep only the mvar=next() and change the mlist.push_back(mvar); with mlist.push_back(new Class1(mvar)); which it would be the thing that i'd like to do, then again im going have a problem because new Class1() expects only an int but there is also the "Terms" parameter. Same problem at index() which expects Class1 object pointer